# Vector functions basic question

Tags: functions, vectors, vector-fields

While evaluating a single variable three component vector function at point $c$, can we also call the three components of the result as three outputs of our function at point $c$?

Comment: Are you talking of $f:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R$ or $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$?

Comment: @user $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

Your function is defined as $$F(t)=<f(t), g(t), h(t)>$$ where $f(t), g(t), h(t)$ are  real valued functions. You may express your function as parametric $$x=f(t), y=g(t), z=h(t)$$

These component functions are the out put  where $t$ is the input of the vector function $F(t)$

For example for a spiral you may have $$x=\sin t, y=\cos t, z=t$$ or $$ S(t) = <\sin t, \cos t, t>$$